# Is videoview supports adaptive streaming in android?

Tags: android, android-videoview, http-live-streaming

In Android is there any way way to support Adaptive Streaming while using Android `VideoView`.

I am playing HLS video inside `VideoView`. Now i want to change the quality of the video based on the bandwidth. if bandwidth is low then `VideoView` should play the low bitrate content and if bandwidth is high then `VideoView` should play the high bitrate video.

I have searched a lot but did not get any satisfactory result.

I have searched the player like `ExoPlayer` they are doing this.

Please follow the below link :

[See Adaptive media playbacks topic of this link](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html)

Please revert if anyone have any idea .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android `VideoView` should be replaced by `ExoPlayer` for various reasons, mainly because third party manufacturers typically modify the `VideoView` causing inconsistent support for things like HLS; for this reason I will base my answer on you using the `ExoPlayer`.

HLS, and other adaptive playback protocols such as DASH or Smooth Stream, automatically changes the playback quality based on the network. In particular, the `HlsRenderBuilder` takes a `BandwidthMeter` (see [HlsRenderBuilder#L131](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v1/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/player/HlsRendererBuilder.java#L131)). If you are worried the default functionality isn't efficient enough then you can provide a customized `BandwithMeter`.

For simplicity you should use a wrapper around the `ExoPlayer` such as [ExoMedia](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia) that provides quick integration with APIs similar to the Android `VideoView`

Comment: Now i have prepare my mind for Exo Player. Thanks for the answer.